# Elasticsearch: How to get the length of a string field(before analysis)?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, full-text-search, analysis

My index has a string field containing a variable length random id. Obviously it shouldn't be analysed.
But I don't know much about elasticsearch especially when I created the index.
Today I tried a lot to filter documents based on the length of id, finally I got this groovy script:

```
doc['myfield'].values.size()
```

or

```
doc['myfield'].value.size()
```

both returns mysterious numbers, I think that's because of the field got analysed.
If it's really the case, is there any way to get the original length or fix the problem, without rebuild the whole index?

Answer (score 5):

Use `_source` instead of `doc`. That's using the source of the document, meaning the initial indexed text:

```
_source['myfield'].value.size()
```

If possible, try to re-index the documents to:

- use `doc[field]` on a `not-analyzed` version of that field
- even better, find out the size of the field **before** you index the document and consider adding its size as a regular field in the document itself

Comment: Of course it will @vineeth-mohan. The same goes for **`script`s in general in ES**. But scripts have their place and can overcome a cluster data design that wasn't been well thought beforehand. And, ideally, that size should have been indexed at the same time with the document as a regular field to overcome the performance toll.

Comment: I just tried _source['myfield'].value,  it says "Cannot get property 'value' on null object". No idea why _source['myfield'] is null.

Comment: Then it seems your field is not stored.

Comment: @AndreiStefan - doc['myfield'] takes data from main memory and is lot more fast compared to _source['myfield'] .

Comment: This does not work for me. I use ES 1.7 and by just changing `doc['text'].value.length() > 200` to `_source['text'].value.length() > 200` I get a `GroovyRuntimeException` telling me `GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingMethodException[No signature of method: [C.length() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

Comment: Found the issue: `_source['text']` returns the value directly whereas with `doc['text']` you have to get the value first. So to solve this I had to use `_source['text'].length()` instead of `doc['text'].value.length()`.

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch stores a string as tokenized in the data structure ( Field data cache )where we have script access to.

So assuming that your field is not not_analyzed , doc['field'].values will look like this

```
"In america" => [ "in" , "america" ]
```

Hence what you get from doc['field'].values is a array and not a string.

Now the story doesn't change even if you have a single token or have the field as not_analyzed.

```
"america" => [ "america" ]
```

Now to see the size of the first token , you can use the following request

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "test1": {
      "script": "doc['field'].values[0].size()"
    }
  }
}
```